# Stop foreach Loop for limited time span in php

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am sending emails to users using *sendgrid* email delivery service.

Below is my code, which send emails to all users of a website.

```
foreach($resident_emails as $email){
     $this->load->model('email_model');
     $this->load->model('preferences_model');
     $user_email = $email->email;
     $admin_email = $from_email;
     $email_row = array('from_email'=>$admin_email,'from_name'=>$from_name,'message'=>$newsletter,'subject'=>$subject);
     $arr_var = array('subject'=>$subject,'message'=>$newsletter);
     $this->email_model->sendEmail($user_email,$email_row,$arr_var);
 }
```

Now for example i have to send email to more than 200 users.

**Problem**

But problem is that, only 10 emails are delivered, and for remaning i received '**FAILED**' status.

**Question**

My question is, how can i stop the execution of `foreach loop` for 10 seconds or more, and then after certain time, next 10 emails sent, and so on?

Comment: There is a `sleep()` function, so `sleep(10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to wait 10 seconds before re-sending a couple of more emails, you can use the [sleep-function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sleep.php) provided by php:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($resident_emails as $email){
    $this->load->model('email_model');
    $this->load->model('preferences_model');
    $user_email = $email->email;
    $admin_email = $from_email;
    $email_row = array('from_email'=>$admin_email,'from_name'=>$from_name,'message'=>$newsletter,'subject'=>$subject);
    $arr_var = array('subject'=>$subject,'message'=>$newsletter);
    $this->email_model->sendEmail($user_email,$email_row,$arr_var);
    $i++;

    // check if this is the nth iteration
    if($i == 10) {
        $i = 0;
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

In the above example, we send 10 emails. On the next iteration, we wait 10 seconds before resending another 10 mails... and so on.

I highly doubt that this will solve your problem, though. Keep in mind that always waiting for 10 seconds raises the execution time.

Comment: So, i have to reduce sleep time ?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer usually, `sleep()` isn't the answer. There are use-cases for sleep, but if sleep is needed, try to lower it in steps to get your desired result, so you don't have to wait for an eternity.

Answer (score 1):

PHP provide in-built function sleep():

```
foreach($resident_emails as $email){
     $this->load->model('email_model');
     $this->load->model('preferences_model');
     $user_email = $email->email;
     $admin_email = $from_email;
     $email_row = array('from_email'=>$admin_email,'from_name'=>$from_name,'message'=>$newsletter,'subject'=>$subject);
     $arr_var = array('subject'=>$subject,'message'=>$newsletter);
     $this->email_model->sendEmail($user_email,$email_row,$arr_var);
     sleep(10);
 }
```